# aws apigateway import-rest-api returns "Invalid base64" error

Tags: amazon-web-services, base64, aws-api-gateway, aws-cli

I am trying to export and than import AWS Gateway API, following the instructions in
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-migrate-accounts-regions/.

Export is working:

```
aws apigateway get-export --parameters extensions='apigateway' --rest-api-id MY_REST_API_ID --stage-name Prod --export-type swagger my-api-apigateway.json
```

Identical files for my API are generated with `--parameters extensions='apigateway'`
and `--parameters extensions='integrations'`.

But when I try to do the import from the exported file:

```
aws apigateway import-rest-api --fail-on-warnings --body file://%cd%/my-api-gateway.json
```

, I am always getting "Invalid base64: " error. Like this:

```
Invalid base64: "{
  "swagger" : "2.0",
  "info" : {
    "version" : "1.0",
    "title" : "my-stack-name"
  },
  "host" : "MY_REST_API_ID.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com",
  "basePath" : "/Prod",
  ...
```

No documentation and no examples on google say that body should be Base64.

The same JSON seems to work when I import it via UI (Actions -> Import API).

I've also tried to use `--cli-input-json`:

`my-api-apigateway-cli-json.json` file (according to `aws apigateway import-rest-api --generate-cli-skeleton`):

```
{
  "failOnWarnings": true,
  "parameters": {
    "endpointConfigurationTypes": "REGIONAL"
  },
  "body": {... JSON FROM EXPORT ...}
}
```

Import command:

```
aws apigateway import-rest-api --cli-input-json file://./my-api-apigateway-cli-json.json
```

, but it says

```
Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter body, value: {'swagger': '2.0', ...
```

So, the questions are:

- Should we encode the json as base64?
- Why is this error and behaviour not documented (or if yes, then where?)?
- How to successfully execute import from cli?

### Useful links

None of the links say that body response should be Base64

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/link-relation/restapi-import/ -- here `body` is clearly documented as `// raw byte array representing the api definition`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

When importing rest-api into AWS API Gateway using the AWS CLI its not mandatory to encode the json as base64.

I suspect you are using AWS CLI v2 and this issue you are facing, I believe it's as a result of changes introduced in [AWS CLI version 2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cliv2-migration.html#cliv2-migration-binaryparam). **i.e**

> AWS CLI version 2 now passes all binary input and binary output
>   parameters as base64-encoded strings by default

***Resolution:***

You will need add ***--cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out*** so that it tells AWS CLI v2 to revert to the AWS CLI v1 behavior:

```
aws apigateway import-rest-api --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out --body file://my-api-apigateway.json
```

Comment: Cool, this seems to work. Really non-obvious.
Looks like my aws-cli version is actually 2.0: `aws --version` shows `aws-cli/2.0.0dev5 Python/3.7.5 Windows/10 botocore/2.0.0dev4`. I thought that aws-cli 2 will be actually executed as `aws2` (this is wrong according to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2-windows.html), and AFAIR I have installed both of them.

Comment: This works for other options for apigateway such as `put-rest-api`

Comment: This should totally be documented in the edge help pages. e.g. `aws apigateway put-rest-api help`

Answer (score 9):

Using `fileb://` instead of `file://` worked for me. For example,

```
aws apigateway import-rest-api --body fileb://my-api.json
```